# Launch python scripts automatically for multiple devices

Tags: python, automation, scripting

I am working for a finance company as part and the valuation team. We have tasks that we launch daily, and I would like to know if there is a way to launch those scripts (Python) automatically without having to use a paid solution like Apache Airflow. Is there a way to easily and automatically execute python scripts on a server (so that if someone is not at the office tasks are still being executed), without that being overly complicated as we are not developers?

We are currently using `.bat` files to execute python scripts, but this is manual and depending on `Python.exe`'s location on each team member's PC, we have to reconfigure the `.bat` file for each one.

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you want these to execute on boot? Or just keep them open in the background (in which case things like `tmux` and `screen` would be good for)?

Comment: on Linux servers standard method is to use `cron` (task scheduler) but Windows should have also scheduler - or you can use python modules like [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/)